# Does turning off features modules affect what the features modules does?

Tags: 7, features

I have a site that uses the media_vimeo module and I need to turn it off to install another module, but I can't turn it off as its currently being used by a bunch of feature modules. Would turning off these features modules affect the site or it doesnt matter as these features modules has already imported the needed changes to the site?

Comment: Since it contains a lot of config in code, yes, disabling a feature will have noticeable impact.

Comment: what are some solutions to turn off this module? i was going to disable it in the database manually in the *systems* table.

Comment: Same thing... if the features define things like info hooks, if the module is disabled, it won't be scanned. Therefore functionality will disappear.

Comment: Nah, deleting the dependency from the features info files would be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I've successfully uninstalled modules required by a feature before, but I had to remove the dependency from the feature's info file first and then disabled and removed the module. I've seen several Features where the creator unwittingly auto-added all sorts of modules and dependencies to the feature, so just because a module is listed as a dependency doesn't necessarily mean that it is really needed. As [this tutorial](http://kerasai.com/blog/2014/04/08/organizing-features-configuration-managment) points out, we should "Build natural dependencies, prevent arbitrary dependencies." and it's so true because as these arbitrary dependencies creep in, a site's features become more difficult to manage.